# Puppeeter Returns Data Weirdly

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I tried to get innerText from several list items and i did it but some words are looking weird. You can understand me if you look at my screenshots.

[image: There is the list items that i tried to catch]

[image: There is the results and my code]

There is the full code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

class Scrape{
    constructor(link, skipCount){
        this.link = link
        this.skip = skipCount
        console.log('CONSTRUCTOR WORKED');
    }
run = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(this.link);
  
    const availabeJobs = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return (
            Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li.thread div.title')).map((item) => item.innerText)
        )
    })

    console.log(availabeJobs);

    await browser.close();
};
}

module.exports = Scrape;
```

Comment: Include your code and errors as text so they're copyable and searchable.

Comment: That page is using `charset=windows-1254` so you might need to take that into consideration.

Comment: I couldnt understand what you tried to say @AndrewMorton

Comment: @questiontoansw Somewhere, the bytes that represent the characters are being interpreted the wrong way. Perhaps you could write the data to a file and open it in a text editor which allows you to change the character encoding and see if the text is revealed as it should be.